# "GSM only" mode in modem settings in tomato router

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, router, tomato

I use Shibby tomato firmware in ASUS-N66U. I use the "3G modem" option in it for WAN. it was working fine till now with my SIM's 3G data plan.
 
I would like to use only 2G data from now, is there any way I can make it connect in "GSM only" mode.

I have both GSM and 3G data available in my sim, but my 3G bandwidth limit for the month is completed (it runs in a very restricted bandwidth). so I would like to connect it in "GSM only" mode to use my GSM/GPRS data. any idea how I can do it in tomato.

I can do the same in ubuntu by editing the Network connection (mobile broadband option) and setting it to "2G(GPRS/EDGE)" mode. In ubuntu before changing the mode to 2G, it connected to HSPDA network, after changing the mode to 2G it connects to the EDGE network. I did try and check the process in commandline to see if any option for 2G mode has been set by ubuntu, but there is no change in the process arguments between the default mode vs 2G mode.

Process in command line:

`/usr/sbin/pppd nodetach lock nodefaultroute ipv6 , ttyUSB0 noipdefault noauth refuse-eap refuse-pap refuse-mschap refuse-mschap-v2 usepeerdns lcp-echo-failure 0 lcp-echo-interval 0 ipparam /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/PPP/5 plugin /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pppd/2.4.5/nm-pppd-plugin.so`